# How should I publish a jar and its dependency to Artifactory?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

I have two jars I wish to publish to Artifactory - let's call them `A.jar` and `B.jar`.
B depends on A.

Should I

a) publish them to the same Artifactory folder e.g. 
`com.x.y.B.some_version`
(where this folder contains both `A.jar` and `B.jar`

b) publish them to separate Artifactory folders e.g.
`com.x.y.A.some_version` and
`com.x.y.B.some_version`

Which will be easier / better for my customers to integrate with when adding those dependencies to their gradle/maven setup?

Comment: Please add a comment for the downvote - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the solution B (one folder per binary).

Next, it should be easy to get them with Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
   <artifactId>A</artifactId>
   <version>some_version</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
   <artifactId>B</artifactId>
   <version>some_version</version>
</dependency>
```